# Assign unique id inside of groups (with duplicated records)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','C','C','C','D','D'],
                   'value': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8],
                  })
```

I would like to create a unique id based on the type and value columns, the output will look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','C','C','C','D','D'],
                   'value': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8],
                   'id': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                  })
```

Comment: Why is `('A', 3)` in the same group as `('C', 6)`?

Comment: you can one hot type column for simple workaround I would say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['id'] = df.groupby('type')['value'].rank('dense').astype(int)
print (df)
   type  value  id
0     A      1   1
1     A      1   1
2     A      2   2
3     B      3   1
4     B      4   2
5     B      5   3
6     B      5   3
7     B      5   3
8     C      6   1
9     C      6   1
10    C      7   2
11    D      7   1
12    D      8   2
```

Or [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
f = lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]
df['id'] = df.groupby('type')['value'].transform(f).add(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
t = df.groupby(['type']).transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
df['id'] = df.groupby(['type', 'value'])[['type', 'value']].apply(lambda x: x.name[1]).reset_index().merge(df, on = ['type', 'value'])[0]-t['value']+1
```

Output:

```
type    value   id
0   A   1   1
1   A   1   1
2   A   2   2
3   B   3   1
4   B   4   2
5   B   5   3
6   B   5   3
7   B   5   3
8   C   6   1
9   C   6   1
10  C   7   2
11  D   7   1
12  D   8   2
```